# JSF passing object to template

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I have two jsf pages. layout.xhtml and page.xhtml. Layout looks like this:

```
<ui:composition>                                                                                                                      
<h:panelGroup id="menu" layout="block">                                                                                           
    <h:outputText value="#{menuBean}" />                                                                                          
    <h:form>                                                                                                                      
        <ui:repeat var="menuItem" value="#{menuBean.menuItems}">                                                                  
            <button:menuItem label="#{msgs[menuItem.label]}" action="#{menuBean.selectItem(menuItem.label)}" update="#{update}" />
        </ui:repeat>                                                                                                              
    </h:form>                                                                                                                     
</h:panelGroup>                                                                                                                   
<ui:repeat var="menuItem" value="#{menuBean.menuItems}">                                                                          
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{menuBean.selectedItemLabel eq menuItem.label}">                                      
        <ui:include src="#{menuItem.page}" />                                                                                     
    </h:panelGroup>                                                                                                               
</ui:repeat>
```

And page like this:

```
<h:panelGroup binding="#{page}" layout="block">             
    <ui:decorate template="../template.xhtml">                   
        <ui:param name="menuBean" value="#{pageBean}" />        
        <ui:param name="update" value=":#{page.clientId}" />
    </ui:decorate>
</h:panelGroup>
```

When I first time render page everything is ok (menuItems are rendered etc). After I click any button I get `Target Unreachable, identifier 'menuBean' resolved to null`.

Can anyone explain me what is happening why the `menuBean` isn't assigned again and if there exists another way to achieve this kind of thing (to have some generic layout page, pass some object there and generate page)? My beans are managed by Spring.

UPDATE:

I guess the problem is somehow connected to my composite button which looks like this:

```
<composite:interface name="menuItem">                                                                                                
    <composite:attribute name="action" targets="button" />                                                                           
    <composite:attribute name="styleClass" />                                                                                        
    <composite:attribute name="label" />                                                                                             
    <composite:attribute name="update" />                                                                                            
    <composite:attribute name="rendered" />                                                                                          
    <composite:insertChildren />                                                                                                     
</composite:interface>                                                                                                               

<composite:implementation>                                                                                                           
    <h:commandButton id="button" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" style="width: 150px;" action="#{cc.attrs.action}"                         
        rendered="#{empty cc.attrs.rendered ? true : cc.attrs.rendered}" styleClass="menu-item #{cc.attrs.styleClass}" type="button">
        <f:ajax render="#{cc.attrs.update}" />                                                                                       
    </h:commandButton>                                                                                                               
</composite:implementation>
```

If I replace the  tag by standard h:commandButton everything works perfectly. I am passing object into template and the template is passing the passed object into composite, but I am definitely missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I am facing to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) already described on his blogspot:
http://balusc.blogspot.cz/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers

Simply put at the moment of postback request (ajax refresh of button) bean passed into my composite button does not exist. As BalusC noted, solution can be creating of standard UIComponent instead of using composite shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is connected with the scope of the beans. As I understand your ***pageBean*** backing bean have request scope. Try to change scope on wider one (it should be view scope @ViewScoped). If you use CDI annotations instead of JSF then you can look at @ConversationalScope (or you can use MyFacesCODI library as Luiggi noted).

Comment: `@ViewScoped` is from JSF, not from PrimeFaces. In CDI, if you want to use `@ViewScoped` you can add MyFacesCODI libraries which add this functionality.

Comment: Yes, I have already undestand my mistace and edited my unswer. And thank you for information about MyFacesCODI, I will look aat it when have time.

Comment: I am using ICEFaces in portlet (Liferay 6) environment. Beans are managed by Spring and my pageBean is ViewScoped :( (Even SessionScope act same)